# PHP form check box from db table (beginner)

Tags: php

Had an a question answered on a different post; now I need to solve the next step! :)

We have a DB that has `secondary_phone_number` as either a `1` or a `0`.

In our View (MVC); I have

```
{
    $secondaryNumber = $company->getSecondaryPhoneNumber();

    if ($secondaryNumber = 1) {
        $data['secondaryphonenumber'] = TRUE;
    } else {
        $data['secondaryphonenumber'] = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Then in our template (HTML), I am trying to display either the checkbox as being checked if Yes (1) or No (2), depending on the DB entry:

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="secondary_phone_number" value="1" {{#secondaryphonenumber}}checked="checked"{{/secondaryphonenumber}}/>
Yes
</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="secondary_phone_number" value="0" {{#secondaryphonenumber}}checked="checked"{{/secondaryphonenumber}}/>
No
</label>
```

The problem is, both checkboxes are displaying as Checked, no matter what the DB says. Any thoughts?

Comment: What MVC framework are you using?

Comment: Flourish MVC (flourishlib.com)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of MVC framework you're using or you made your own framework, but your approach doesn't really care what is in `secondaryphonenumber` when generating checkbox

try something like this

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="secondary_phone_number" value="1" <?=$secondaryphonenumber?"checked":""?>/>
Yes
</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="secondary_phone_number" value="0"  <?=$secondaryphonenumber?"":"checked"?>/>
No
</label>
```

But I'd suggest using radio button instead because checkbox allows user to select both options.

Comment: Its the Flourish MVC (flourishlib.com), and we are using mustache. Still cant get the dang thing to work.

Comment: I've never heard of this MVC, but in general, you should do an if else check on the secondaryphonenumber variable, if it's true, echo "checked" in checkbox 1, echo nothing if it's false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$secondaryNumber = $company->getSecondaryPhoneNumber();

if ($secondaryNumber = 1) {
    $data['secondaryphonenumber'] = TRUE;
} else {
    $data['secondaryphonenumber_false'] = TRUE;
}

<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="secondary_phone_number" value="1" {{#secondaryphonenumber}}checked="checked"{{/secondaryphonenumber}}/>
Yes
</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="secondary_phone_number" value="0" {{#secondaryphonenumber_false}}checked="checked"{{/secondaryphonenumber_false}}/>
No
</label>
```

Comment: I have made the changes. Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="secondary_phone_number" value="1" <?php if($data['secondaryphonenumber'] == TRUE){?>checked="checked"<?php }?>/>
Yes
</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="secondary_phone_number" value="0" <?php if($data['secondaryphonenumber'] == FALSE){?>checked="checked"<?php }?>/>
No
</label>
Using radio button will be a better option..
```